# Firebird in Manjaro - Error while trying to open file Permission denied

Tags: permissions, firebird, manjaro

I'm having some problem when I try to connect my Firebird database using FlameRobin.

I'm getting this error

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS3Wl.png)

So I tried this in terminal:

```
ls -l /home/rainan/Projetos/firebird/tabelas/glotes/TABELAS.GDB
```

and I get the output

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 rainan firebird 113360896 mai 31 17:14 /home/rainan/Projetos/firebird/tabelas/glotes/TABELAS.GDB
```

So, I don't know why I'm still having permission denied when I try to connect my database.

Comment: your screenshot shows another folder though, `-Projetos` not `Projetos`

Comment: Firebird is a server process, it can't access database files in your home directory. Put it in a location that is accessible by the Firebird service.

Comment: @Arioch'The I wonder if that might be hyphenation that is applied when wrapping the error message.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i wondered too, but it would be very strange to do so, that is not any programmming language or formal markup, where explicit non-separating EOL should be marked, it is mere UI. Also, what specifically precludes daemons from accessing homedirs? I did not used Linux seriously for ages, but i remember when i did i had `~/public_html` and Apache clearly was a daemon! I would rather expect SuperServer/Embedded races over exclusive file open

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't regularly use Linux, but IIRC, Firebird server will also need rights on the directory containing the database (eg to be able to write the difference file when in 'backup mode'). I think I wrote an answer to that effect a while ago, but I couldn't find it, and I don't have time to test things out again. But still, putting the database accessed by a server process in the user home directory is not a good idea.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel will FB write some extended info into log-file then? or strace/procmon is what si left for diagnosing

Comment: Hey bro @MarkRotteveel,  I use this same directory(in my home directory) in my Ubuntu notebook, the same database (firebird 2.5) and my firebird service has access with no problem, so I don't know that what you said is really the problem.

Comment: Then possibly the server process itself is run by a user that is not in the firebird group.

Comment: A quick check on Ubuntu shows that my initial comment was wrong. I think it might be better to ask your question on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/firebird-support). I would still recommend to check if the user running the Firebird server process is actually a member of the firebird group. And as Arioch 'The suggested: double check the filename, the presence of that `-` in the filename seems odd.

Comment: Ok, i'll check the firebird-support Google Group and if I find any solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: I did some testing on Manjaro, and I can reproduce the behaviour, where the same action seems to work fine on Ubuntu (though I tested with 2.5.9 on Manjaro and with 3.0.5 on Ubuntu).

Comment: I'm unsure if this is a difference between those two Firebird versions or between Manjaro and Ubuntu. In any case, the workaround would be to put the database file in `/var/lib/firebird` instead of your home directory.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel did you use TCP connection strring or local connection string? I still suspect it might be embedded server related somehow.

Comment: @Arioch'The AFAIK, FlameRobin only supports TCP connection. The hostname is required IIRC.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel FlameRobin 0.9.2 IB++ 2.5.2 (help/about says (c) 2009 but i have doubts, i got that computer at 2013 or maybe later) on Win7x64 -> Register Server: do **NOT** fill TCP boxes, everything but the name leave empty -> Register DB -> `select MON$Remote_Protocol from MON$ATTACHMENTS` -> `XNET`

Comment: @Arioch'The XNET is a windows only named pipes protocol, so not embedded. However, that is beside the point. I can reproduce the problem that the OP observed, even when the file has the proper group assigned. I'm not enough of a Linux user to diagnose this further though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel XNET is, but my point was not XNET itself but that FlameRobin allows local, non-TCP connections. At least that old one, at least unofficially. P.S. named pipes is WNET, XNET is mutexes+shared memory